# increment if not same value of next column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I am trying to use the Row Number in SQL. However, it's not giving desired output.

Data :

```
ID   Name  Output should be
111   A     1
111   B     2
111   C     3
111   C     3
111   A     4

222   A     1
222   A     1
222   B     2 
222   C     3 
222   B     4
222   B     4
```

Comment: Why are you using unsupported software?  SQL Server 2008 has been out of support for years.  Also SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  You question makes no sense unless a column specifies the ordering.

Answer (score 4):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem. As a starter: for the question to just make sense, you need a column that defines the ordering of the rows - I assumed `ordering_id`. Then, I would recommend `lag()` to get the "previous" `name`, and a cumulative `sum()` that increases everytime the `name` changes in adjacent rows:

```
select id, name,
    sum(case when name = lag_name then 0 else 1 end) over(partition by id order by ordering_id) as rn
from (
    select t.*, lag(name) over(partition by id order by ordering_id) lag_name
    from mytable t
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2008 makes this much trickier.  You can identify the adjacent rows using a difference of rows numbers.  Then you can assign the minimum id in each island and use `dense_rank()`:

```
select t.*,
       dense_rank() over (partition by name order by min_ordcol) as output
from (select t.*,
             min(<ordcol>) over (partition by name, seqnum - seqnum_2) as min_ordcol
      from (select t.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by name order by <ordcol>) as seqnum,
                   row_number() over (partition by name, id order by <ordcol>) as seqnum_2
            from t
           ) t
      ) t;
```